# if else statement javascript to make div change color based on .scrollTop

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner coder and I'm trying to change the background color of a div based on how far down scrolled the webpage is, where am I going wrong?
Do I need to put in something to call the scrollTop amount?

```
(function () { 
    var scroll = .scrollTop;

if (scroll > 50) {
      document.getElementByClassName("shop").style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
    }
    else
    {
document.getElementByClassName("shop").style.backgroundColor = ‘red’;

    }
  })();
```

Comment: You're using stylized quotes, which are incorrect syntax.  (And are also a very common reason why a word processor should never be mistaken for an IDE.)  Additionally, the class name is just "shop", no leading period is needed there.  Aside from that, what `scrollTop` are you looking for?  You forgot to put anything *before* that property.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment... You're defining a variable named `scrole` but then trying to use a variable named `scroll`.  Also, nothing ever executes this function in the first place.  In short, there's *a lot* wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Using a dot before a class name when getting it in javascript using getElementsByClassName is an Incorrect Syntax. Below is the correct syntax.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("shop")
```

Tip: Always Use the console window to monitor your Syntax and other errors.

Answer (score 1):

Many errors in the code....
`var scrole = .scrollTop;` not sure if you are trying to assign any value or is it window.scrollTop.
`document.getElementByClassName(".shop")` should be changed to `document.getElementByClassName("shop")`
`else if (scroll < 50 ){ //statement }` to be changed to `else { //statement }`
function is wrapped in small bracket but has never been invoked.
Self invoking function example :-
`(function(){
    console.log(Math.PI);
})();`

Answer (score 1):

Lose the dot, instead of “.shop” go for “shop”

And the actual function getElement**s**ByClassName and it returns a collections of divs with the class name. But you need the first one (assuming you have only one such div) hence the 0 index in array

```
parentDOM.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
 <p class="test">hello here</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code are only executed once if you don't attach a `listener`. Let me just use these code from MDN docs with a bit of edit. [The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event)

```js
let last_known_scroll_position = 0;
let ticking = false;

function doSomething(scroll_pos) {
  if (scroll_pos > 50) {
    document.querySelector(“.shop”).style.backgroundColor = '#99C262';
  } else if (scroll_post < 50) {
    document.querySelecttor(“.shop”).style.backgroundColor = ‘red’;
  } else {
    // add more colorrrs!
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;

  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
      ticking = false;
    });

    ticking = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: getElementByClassName is not a function. You should use getElementsByClassName instead. And putting a dot before a class name when trying to get it using getElementsByClassName is a wrong syntax. Consider using querySelector() or querySelectorAll().